# RedBeanPHP loading beans 'id' not found

Tags: redbean

Good Day,

I am trying to load some data from RedBean from my PHP table:

R::freeze( true );

$idfunctions=1;
$function = R::load('functions', $idfunctions); 
if (!$function->id) { echo "...help bean not found!!.."; }

The table functions has a primary key column called idfunctions. However, the library keeps assuming my id column is "id". Is there anyway I can set it to idfunctions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redbean expects certain schema configurations. One of them is a primary key named id. Please read this page carefully for the others.
http://www.redbeanphp.com/schema

Comment: Sigh, I wish there was some kind of library that could automatically generate PHP Objects dynamically from my MySQL Table. I mean, I could technically develop one myself, albeit with a week or two of programming, but I'm surprised it doesn't exist yet

Comment: RB is doing exactly that but since there are different rdbms and ways to work with them there need to be some prerequisites to make it doing the job automatically. If thats a show-stopper for you check out the new roadmap. http://www.redbeanphp.com/roadmap

Answer (score 0):

first of all ,
  u cant change the "id" field. because it is already defined bydefault in "rb.php".

but if you want you can change there in rb.php file.But that is not a good idea to do that.

so better avoid this and follow the red bean schema type.

HAppy coding